# Make async call from Vue component to NodeJs server and wait for answer

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, vue.js

What I'm trying to accomplish is this: I have a Server running Vue.js. After "npm run dev" the app is displayed on localhost:8080 . Now after everything is built, this piece of code in a component is executed:
(I have a NodeJs server running on port 3000)

**HelloWorld.Vue**

```
mounted () {  
  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/')
    .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    this.User = response.data;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

}

Which will basically ask the NodeJS Server to perform a query on a Post Gres database.

**Server.Js**

```
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    return res.send(connectBD());
});

function connectBD(){ 

    res =  client.query("Select * from entidademeio");

    res.rows.forEach(row=>{
        console.log(row);
        tmp = JSON.stringify(row['nomeentidade']) + "";
        queryResult += tmp;         //Imprime as rows da b
    });
    client.end();
    return queryResult;
}
```

But i get this error from the Vue side:

> ```
> Request failed with status code 500
> at createError (createError.js?16d0:16)
> at settle (settle.js?db52:18)
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?ec6c:77)
> ```

However if i return a string :

**Server.Js**

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     return res.send("bla");
});
```

it gets displayed like i wanted in the console on the Vue Side. Can somebody please provide me with a solution and some code snippets.I want the result of the query to be displayed on the console from Vue Side. Thanks

EDIT:

If I change my ConnectBD() to:

```
async function connectBD(){ 
var conString = "postgres://**********************";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
var result;
await client.connect();

res = await client.query("Select * from entidademeio");

res.rows.forEach(row=>{
    console.log(row);
    tmp = JSON.stringify(row['nomeentidade']) + "";
    result += tmp;         //Imprime as rows da b
});
await client.end();
console.log(result);
return result;
```

}

I get an empty array from Vue side but the terminal from node is returning the correct result.

NEW EDIT: The empty array:
[The empty array on the console from Vue Side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md9iA.png)